# What is the use of VIDEOEXPOSE in pygame?

Tags: pygame

I dont really understand the utility of this event type. It seems to appear at the same time as the VIDEORESIZE event but it does not have any attribute like the QUIT event. The official documentation of pygame events does not talk about this one http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html... Does anyone know why this event type was created ?

Comment: "[Hardware displays](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html) that draw direct to the screen will get pygame.VIDEOEXPOSE events when portions of the window must be redrawn." Don't ask me how it works.

Comment: It seems you gave me a good answer... Why did you only put it in comment?

Comment: I wasn't sure if it was sufficient as an answer. I really don't know much about this topic, but I'd like to learn more about hardware surfaces and using OpenGL in pygame (I think I should better use pyglet), so hopefully someone else can add some explanations. Your question is good.

Comment: I get `pygame.VIDEOEXPOSE` when I move to another tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [`pygame.display`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html) documentation:

> Hardware displays that draw direct to the screen will get pygame.VIDEOEXPOSE events when portions of the window must be redrawn.